# Generating Excel documents with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

I need to generate Excel documents with Ruby (from Rails) on a Linux machine.
I know of Spreadsheet::Excel, but it doesn't support formulas, and uses a pretty old format.

Is there any other option, not necessarily free or open source, that is a bit more powerful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053240/how-should-i-capitalize-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about opening a spreadsheet (Spreadsheet::Excel) with the formulae already populated. Entering data into the referenced cells will cause them to display the result.

Comment: that, my friend, is an awesome idea I somehow hadn't thought of! My thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about https://github.com/randym/axlsx

This gem can easily generate spreadsheets in the OOXML format (Open Office XML)

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the gem [simple_xlsx_writer](http://rubygems.org/gems/simple_xlsx_writer).

You can see the example of how to use it over [here](http://www.getharvest.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-generate-excel-files-with-ruby/).

Hope it helps.