# How to generate an Excel file with Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spreadsheet, export-to-excel

I was searching Ruby toolbox for a popular, well-supported tool to generate XSLX (Excel 2007 and on) document, but I didn't manage to find anything.
I also spent a good amount of time searching on Google, but most of the answers I found seem outdated.

**I'll need to include inline images in the document I generate.**

I'm working with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow as well?

Comment: Yup, though I found nothing that has to do with a Ruby library doing that. I found a .Net solution, but digging into it wasn't helpful

Comment: Had you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887518/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-with-formulas-using-rails or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227973/generating-excel-documents-with-ruby or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644341/which-gem-support-import-export-to-xlsx-file-in-ruby ?

Comment: Yep, but none include any help on adding images to the spreadsheet (at least not on a mac)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Bit late to the game, but there you go.
You should use the axlsx gem

On Github:
https://github.com/randym/axlsx

On Rubygems:
https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx

On Rubytookbox:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/axlsx

From the README

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.workbook do |wb|
  wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Image with Hyperlink") do |sheet|
    img = File.expand_path('../image1.jpeg', __FILE__)
    sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true,  :hyperlink=>"http://axlsx.blogspot.com") do |image|
      image.width=720
      image.height=666
      image.hyperlink.tooltip = "Labeled Link"
      image.start_at 2, 2
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Belatedly realized that I should have pointed out the rails gem for this library as well. You still get all the power of axlsx - but it automate the column/row generation for any AR inheriting object with localization. Really helps speed up your report generation in rails as you dont have to roll a report for all your models.

Comment: This gem helped me a lot, thanks! Even if the answer came late, is great. A good reason to answer to questions after a lot of time ;)

Comment: Oh man, you are the creator of the gem! Didn't notice it! Expect some donations, I'm experimenting with your gem and is great, I'm using it in my current project.

Comment: glad you like it. feel free to grab me on irc if you have any questions. if you are on rails, you should have a look at axlsx_rails https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails as well.

Comment: Yea I watched your blog and found it. I!m following your examples

Comment: @randym Can this gem handle reading images from an uploaded excel file as well as inserting them?

Comment: @randym Your axlsx gem looks wonderful and the axlsx_rails addition is great, too.  Now, if I can just figure out how to type them without constantly misspelling them... (grin)  Really, thanks for the great code.

Answer (score 10):

I've used the [spreadsheet gem](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/). Here is some code that I've used to write it to a file and send.

```
spreadsheet_name = @role.title

   book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new 
   sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => spreadsheet_name

   @people.each_with_index  { |person, i| 
     sheet1.row(i).replace [person.first_name, person.last_name, person.email, person.title, person.organization, person.phone, person.street, person.street2, person.city, person.state, person.zip, person.country]
   }        

   export_file_path = [Rails.root, "public", "uploads", "exports", "#{ @team.sort_name }_#{ DateTime.now.to_s }.xls"].join("/")
   book.write export_file_path
   send_file export_file_path, :content_type => "application/vnd.ms-excel", :disposition => 'inline'
```

There is probably a way to do this in memory and not write a file.. but I didn't take the time to look into it.

### I didn't see the inline images need, but I'll leave this because it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this gem

> https://github.com/harvesthq/simple_xlsx_writer

And

> https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel/

Comment: I stumbled upon it, but it is a 'simple' writer, in that it doesn't allow for special insertions such as images. That is, of course, unless I am missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: @yuval, I think that there is no any gem which can do this job